# How to control outputting data in @foreach

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

How can I control the number of outputting data in @foreach section?
For ex, in @foreach(var x in Model){} I want to get only first 10 data in that model, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Either use a `for` loop or use Linq's `Take()` extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Model is a collection type(Ex :`IEnumerable<T>`), You can use LINQ `Take` method.

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>
@{ var tenItems = Model.Take(10);}  // Get the 10 items from the collection
@foreach (var x in tenItems)
{
    <p>@x.Name</p>
}
```

Also, If you want you can order by the results before taking the 10 items,

```
@{ var tenItems = Model.OrderBy(s=>s.SomePropertyOfYourClass).Take(10);}
```

Comment: Oh, so easy! Thanks a lot!